# Regular Expression to catch a scriplet tag

Tags: jsp, session, scriptlet

I am trying to create a regular expression to check the occurrence of scriptlet tags in the jsp pages.

Here is the regex that I am using:

```
\<%(\s+)((.+?)(\n)*(\s+))*%>
```

The problem I am facing here is that, although there are 3 separate instances to be flagged ideally, but my regex is flagging it all at once.

My requirement is to flag the individual instances only. And not the intermediate codes.

Here is the test code that I am using to test my regex:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%
  // Get session creation time.
   Date createTime = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
   // Get last access time of this web page.
   Date lastAccessTime = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());

   String title = "Welcome Back to my website";
   Integer visitCount = new Integer(0);
    String visitCountKey = new String("visitCount");
   String userIDKey = new String("userID");
   String userID = new String("ABCD");

   // Check if this is new comer on your web page.
   if (session.isNew()){
     title = "Welcome to my website";
      session.setAttribute(userIDKey, userID);
       session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,  visitCount);
   } 
    visitCount = (Integer)session.getAttribute(visitCountKey);
  visitCount = visitCount + 1;
  userID = (String)session.getAttribute(userIDKey);
  session.setAttribute(visitCountKey,  visitCount);
 %>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Session Tracking</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>
 <h1>Session Tracking</h1>
</center>
<table border="1" align="center"> 
<tr bgcolor="#949494">
   <th>Session info</th>
  <th>Value</th>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
   <td>id</td>
   <td><% out.print( session.getId()); %></td>
</tr> 
  <tr>
   <td>Creation Time</td>
   <td><% out.print(createTime); %></td>
  </tr> 

  </table> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: What are the tags? Are they the same, need more description.

Comment: I just need to catch the occurence of "<% any data here %>". Every occurence of scriptlets, no matter what data is present in between the starting and ending tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `regex` that matches only the tags:

```
(<%).*?(%>)
```

Or you want to return only what is in between:

```
<%(.*?)%>
```

Then replace to the first group `\1` matched.

If you want the `.` to match also new lines, use the `(?s)` modifier:

```
(?s)<%(.*?)%>
```

Demo here:

https://regex101.com/r/jX9bX0/8

Comment: The above regex catches the one liner tags only. For e.g.                                              <% out.print( session.getId()); %>.                                                                         But for cases where there are multiple lines inside the tag, then this becomes ineffective. Which is exactly what I am looking for.                                    For e.g Below code must be flagged                                                     <%
              String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
            session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
          %>

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is exactly what I was looking for. :)